# SS 2008 R2 Analysis Services - Class not registered

Tags: mdx, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas

I have a fresh 64 bit SS 2008 R2 install on a new server running 64 bit Windows 7. (No previous versions of SS). BIDS is running on the same box as SS 2008 R2.

I ran the Analysis Services tutorial, to build the first cube, based on AdventureWorks DB. All is well until I get to "Deploy Cube" The deploy status is "Succeeded" but...

The browser tab of the Cube View gives this error and no UI:

Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)

I have read many blogs on this. Several refer to re-registering DTS and DTSCONN DLLs, Windows Office Component problems, user priveleges, etc. I do not think I have the answer yet.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downloading and installing the Office 2003 Web Components DLL cured this very problem for me.
Don't worry that the DLL is 32 bit. It still cures the problem.
The cube is displayed using this DLL.

The same fix applies for the Visual Studio 2008 Business Intelligence Builder.

Link:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=7287252c-402e-4f72-97a5-e0fd290d4b76&displaylang=en